# Android handler handleMessage() method call

Tags: java, android, handler

When we instantiate a `Handler` object (for this example lets say I am using anonymous inner class) in the main UI thread.

```
Handler h = new Handler () {
    @override
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        /* Code to handle the message */
    }
};
```

We can just pass this `Handler` object reference to some other thread who can post status updates to the UI thread using this reference (`h.sendMessage()`).

Doubt: We have not provided our custom anonymous class reference `h` `Handler` anywhere to the `Activity` class or the UI thread. In order to call the overridden method UI thread must have the object reference to our class. So how would the overridden `handleMessage()` be called instead of the default one?

Comment: I don't understand last paragraph. Can you describe it in different way?

Comment: I believe both work on main thread and can access methods and variables.

Comment: @DominikSuszczewicz Have modified some statements. Please try it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `handleMessage()` is being called by the `Looper`. You can see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#148) that looper calls dispatchMessage on message target which is a [Handler](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Message.java#103). And target is being assigned a `this` reference when you [post a message](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#626) inside handler. So the flow is as follows:

1. you post a message on your handler, internally it creates a Message object with a reference to its handler.
2. that message is put to a message queue managed by the main UI thred (in this particular case)
3. when time comes, Android is removing your message from the queue and using its target field - calls handleMesage on it.

Also - whats important is that if you dont specify particular Looper when creating Handler, then default Looper is used for the thread where it is being instantiated. In you case its Main UI Looper.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `h.sendEmptyMessage()`